# Page url is not changing on redirecting

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a jquery popup login in my masterpage having contentPage url

> Category.aspx

and in code behind i have written

```
public void Ligin_Click( object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    string Ret = objLogin.LoginValidate(
                               txtSignInEmail.Text.Trim(), 
                               txtSignInPass.Text.Trim());
     if (Ret == "1")
     {
         Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Home.aspx?");
     }
}
```

but `Response.Redirect` was not working then i have written

```
Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Home.aspx?",false);
```

and it is working fine. but page url is not changing it remains previous page url

> Category.aspx

and  link button  on Home.aspx is not working, throwing exception.
Invalid postback or callback argument.
Event validation is enabled  using

```
<pages enableEventValidation="true"/>
```

in configuration or

```
<%@Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
```

For security  purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback
events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.
If the data is valid and expected, use the
ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation 
     method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

---

when i am typing url 'home.aspx' manualy , it is working fine.

Comment: What does **string  Ret ** contains. Is it returns "1" or boolen value ?

Comment: Because there is a wide range of abuse of word "popup", how does you popup looks? Do you create a popup with 'window.open()' or with <div> element?

Comment: string Ret is return "1",

Comment: and i have use jquery popup

Comment: Ok @Durgesh ,remove "?" from  Response.Redirect("~/Mobile/Home.aspx?")

Comment: i have remove , but still not working.

Comment: for popup i am using js jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js

Comment: The JQuery Pop-up is rendered inside an Update Panel?

Comment: no it not in update panel but when i put linkbutton outside of popup it is working fine.

Comment: @Durgesh Is "Mobile" is your directory in Root. in your redirect url.

Comment: now i got solution, i have change login Button to linkbutton and now it is working fine...:) . i don't know y it is working with linkbutton not with button

Answer (score 8):

jQuery Mobile and asp.net web forms fundamentally don't work together. The postback model and jQuery Mobile's ajax form loading and navigation are incompatible. Move to MVC or turn off ajax.

Make sure to invoke this code before jQuery Mobile initializes. (Include it before the `<script>` tag that references jQuery Mobile.)

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are stuck with trying your best to marry jQuery Mobile and ASP.NET WebForms, you can use the `data-url` attribute on your `data-role="page"` `div` to work around your problem of server-side redirection messing with the browser URL.

Use something equivalent to the following, in your .aspx:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="<%= Request.Url.PathAndQuery %>">
...
</div>
```

For more details, read the section titled "Redirects and linking to directories" on [this jQuery Mobile doc page](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/page-links.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable ajax, you may do so on the element where it will not be needed with: data-ajax="false". You may place this on the form to handle the response redirects. (However, this will not disable ajax entirely--for links as an example.)

You may add a simple script section with window.onload or whatever your favorite jquery init and disable form ajax just for that page with $('form').attr("data-ajax", "false");